# Subir archivo pdf laravel

Tags: pdf, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, laravel-9

Estoy usando la plantilla de AdminLte con laravel 9 y jetstream.
Tengo una tabla en la base de datos llamada proyectos. En esa tabla hay un campo de name 'documento' a donde va el archivo en pdf. Me carga el nombre del archivo cuando lo subo pero no me carga el archivo en la carpeta que le asigno con Storage::put.
Me podrian ayudar. Estuve leyendo otras preguntas que concuerdan en parte con la mia, pero no doy en la tecla. Paso las capturas de pantallas del codigo.

Archivo Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    return view('admin.proyectos.index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $categorias = Categoria::pluck('name', 'id');
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('admin.proyectos.create', compact('categorias', 'users', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{

    $proyecto = Proyecto::create($request->all());

    if ($request->file('documento')) {
        
        $url = Storage::put('documentos', $request->file('documento'));
        $proyecto->image()->create([
            'url' => $url
        ]);
    }

    if($request->tags){
        $proyecto->tags()->attach($request->tags);
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.proyectos.edit', $proyecto);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Proyecto $proyecto)
{
    return view('admin.proyectos.show', compact('proyecto'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Proyecto $proyecto)
{
    $categorias = Categoria::pluck('name', 'id');
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('admin.proyectos.edit', compact('proyecto', 'categorias', 'users', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Proyecto $proyecto)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Proyecto $proyecto)
{
    //
}
```

Archivo Model:

```
use HasFactory;

protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

//Relación de UNO a MUCHOS inversa
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function categoria(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
}

//Relación de MUCHOS a MUCHOS
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}

//Relación UNO a UNO Polimorfica
public function image(){
    return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

Formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el nombre del proyecto']) !!}
    @error('name')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('slug', 'Slug:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el slug del proyecto', 'readonly']) !!}
    @error('slug')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('user_id', 'Cliente:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('user_id', $users, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    @error('user_id')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('categoria_id', 'Categoria:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('categoria_id', $categorias, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    @error('categoria_id')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('tag_id', 'Etiqueta:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('tag_id', $tags, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    @error('tag_id')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('extracto', 'Extracto:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('extracto', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el extracto del proyecto']) !!}
    @error('extracto')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('body', 'Descripción del proyecto:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese una descripción del proyecto']) !!}
    @error('body')
    <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
@enderror
</div>
<div>
    <h5 class="mb-3">Archivo Adjunto</h3>
</div>
{{-- <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img id="documentoid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/24/20/30/architecture-1857175_960_720.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('documento', 'Documento que se mostrara en el proyecto') !!}
            {!! Form::file('documento', ['class' => 'form-control-file']) !!}
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus est culpa a dolor, numquam placeat illo consectetur voluptatum in hic quos deserunt vel perspiciatis earum itaque velit, accusamus neque ipsam?</p>
    </div>
</div> --}}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('documento', 'Documento adjunto:') !!}
    <br>
    {!! Form::file('documento', ['class' => 'form-control-file']) !!}
</div>
```

Espero poder recibir alguna ayuda y si en algun SO esta la respuesta pido disculpas de antemano!

Comment: {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.proyectos.store', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'files' => true]) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) !!}
                @include('admin.proyectos.partials.form')
                {!! Form::submit('Crear Proyecto', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}

Comment: Deberia cambiar el 'files' => true por el multipart/form-data?

Comment: "documento" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#32 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "La_Rebelion_de_Atlas.pdf"
        -mimeType: "application/pdf"
        -error: 0
        path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
        filename: "phpF950.tmp"
        basename: "phpF950.tmp"
        pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF950.tmp"
        extension: "tmp"
        realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF950.tmp"

Comment: me envia el archivo a una carpeta temporal

Comment: Si me lo guarda en la carpeta pero me cambia el nombre del archivo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Todabia no lo resolvi porque no se como usar putFileAs ya que Storage::putFileAs('documentos', $request->file('documento')); me tira un error que no se resolver aun. Perdon por mi poca experiencia en laravel. @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 1):

Empecemos desde el principio.

```
$url = Storage::put('documentos', $request->file('documento'));
```

En esa línea, hay un problema, y es que el método `put` es para almacenar el contenido de un archivo en un disco. Pero tú no tienes el contenido, sino que tienes el archivo en sí. Ref: [Storing Files](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#storing-files).

Por lo tanto, deberías usar otro método, como `putFile`, que sí espera un archivo

```
$url = Storage::putFile('documentos', $request->file('documento'));
```

Otra cosa, ten en cuenta que solo especificamos un nombre de directorio (`'documentos'`), no un nombre de archivo. De forma predeterminada, el método `putFile` generará una identificación única para que sirva como nombre de archivo, y la extensión del archivo se determinará examinando el tipo MIME del archivo.

El método `putFile` devolverá el path al archivo para que puedas almacenarlo, incluido el nombre de archivo generado, en tu base de datos. Por lo tanto, el nombre de esa variable a la que asignas el resultado puede resultar confusa, y sería más apropiado

```
$path = Storage::putFile('documentos', $request->file('documento'));
```

Ref: [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads)

Además, si lo que quieres es que el archivo conserve el nombre y extensión original del archivo cargado, puedes hacerlo utilizando los métodos `getClientOriginalName` y `getClientOriginalExtension`. Ref: [Other Uploaded File Information](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#other-uploaded-file-information)

```
$file = $request->file('documento');
 
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Para luego usarlo con el método `putFileAs`, que recibe el directorio, el archivo y el nombre que quieras darle como argumentos. Ref: [Specifying A File Name](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

```
$path = Storage::putFileAs(
    'documentos', $request->file('documento'), $request->file('documento')->getClientOriginalName()
);
```

Comment: Hice lo que me dijistes. El archivo logra ingresar a la carpeta con el nombre original pero en la base de datos me figura de esta manera el archivo: C:\xampp\tmp\php8349.tmp y no con el nombre Este_es_un.pdf. Que puede estar faltando

Comment: es de esa forma que se almacena el nombre del archivo o hay algo que esta mal?

Comment: public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $proyecto = Proyecto::create($request->all());
        $file = $request->file('documento');
        $name = $request->file('documento')->getClientOriginalName();

        if ($request->file('documento')) {

            $url = Storage::putFileAs('documentos', $file, $name);
            $proyecto->image()->create([
                'url' => $url
            ]);
        }

Comment: @GuillermoLeonardo En la base de datos en que tabla? Si hiciste `$proyecto->image()->create([ 'url' => $url ]);` tienes que mirar en la tabla que corresponda a esa relación `image` o sea, en la tabla que corresponde al model Image